# How do I sum using for distinct items in a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to show my table data in sort order by `design_no`

Here is my data

```
design_no  fname       meter    rate        s   m    l  xl
---------------------------------------------------------------
3092       2111-1      432.00   235.00      32  33  21  21
3092       2111-1      498.75   235.00      38  37  24  24
3092       2111-1      460.50   235.00      31  35  23  24
3092       2111        501.75   245.00      37  38  25  24
```

I want show it like this..

```
design_no    fname    meter     rate          pcs
---------------------------------------------------
3092         2111     501.75    245.00        124
3092         2111-1   1391.25   235.00        343
```

Kindy help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT design_no,fname,SUM(meter),rate,SUM(s)+SUM(m)+SUM(l)+SUM(xl)
FROM tab
GROUP BY design_no,fname,rate
```

What behaviour do you want if the rate is different for the same design_no and fname?

Comment: Column 'tab.rate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: @HaiderAli Did you copy it correctly? I have it in the group by

Comment: Can you double check if it was copied correctly? the error doesnt make sense given that rate is present in the group by

Comment: thanks dear you are great :)
how to select via design_no in this qurey ??

Comment: how to select via design_no in this qurey ??

Comment: Type `WHERE design_no= xyz` in the line after `FROM` to filter, type 'ORDER BY design_no' in the line after group by to sort it